# HSTS and access to subdomain with Javascript

Tags: javascript, https, hsts

Some weeks ago I have moved a homepage to https only and also enabled HSTS. On one page I have some JavaScript code that got its content from a subdomain via a http-request. Before https was enabled this worked well. I also changed the http protocol to https in the javascript code. But this was not a solution.

Does HTTPS restrict access to a subdomain or is it HSTS?

Is there a way to allow access to subdomains?

Here ist the JavaScript-Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#ipv4").show().load('https://ipv4.mydomain.com/myip/'
, {limit: 25}, 
  function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
    if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#ipv4").html("Kein IPv4");
    }
  }
);
$("#ipv6").show().load('https://ipv6.mydomain.com/myip/'
, {limit: 25}, 
  function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
    if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#ipv6").html("Kein IPv6");
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

And this is the HSTS-Header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Comment: What is your HSTS header?

Comment: I have added the HSTS-header in my post, and also the subdomains have valid certificates.

Comment: so hsts apply to your subdomains. What do ssllabs says about them?

Answer (score 0):

The only effect of HSTS is to rewrite http request to https before sending them.

Thus, your subdomain must answer to https request to works.